# User Column blank in Elmah_Error table

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, elmah

I'm using `ELMAH` to log errors within my `mvc Website`. The errors are saving within `ELMAH_ERROR` table in my `SQL` Database. I'm using Forms authentication. However when a user is logged into my system and they receive an error which then inserts into the `ELMAH_ERROR` table, the name of the user is not inserting. How do I fix this?

Comment: please show your some code

Comment: I am using following function to log the error       public static void Log(Exception ex)
        {
            if (HttpContext.Current != null)//website is logging the error
            {

                var elmahCon = Elmah.ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext();
                elmahCon.Raise(ex);
            }
            else//non website, probably an agent
            {
                var elmahCon = Elmah.ErrorLog.GetDefault(null);
                elmahCon.Log(new Elmah.Error(ex));
            }
        }

Comment: it logs perfectly in db except the username or id